# Returning parseInt in JS gives me undefined

Tags: javascript, return, parseint

This seems really strange to me. When I console log the answer in `console.log(parseInt(a,2))` it prints the correct value. but when I console log the return of the function I get undefined.

## JS Code

```
var addRec = function(a, b, not_first) {
    if (!not_first) return addRec(a.toString(2), b.toString(2), true);
    if (b === 0 || b === '0') {
        console.log(parseInt(a, 2)); // prints 3
        return parseInt(a, 2);
    }

    var carry = a & b;
    var a = a ^ b;
    var b = carry << 1;
    addRec(a, b, true);
};

console.log(addRec(1, 2)); // prints undefined
```

Comment: `return addRec(a, b, true);`

Comment: You forgot to `return` the recursive call at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to return at the end of the function. A function which returns nothing gives `undefined`.

```
var addRec = function(a, b, not_first) {
    if (!not_first) return addRec(a.toString(2), b.toString(2), true);
    if (b === 0 || b === '0') {
        console.log(parseInt(a, 2)); // prints 3
        return parseInt(a, 2);
    }

    var carry = a & b;
    var a = a ^ b;
    var b = carry << 1;
    return addRec(a, b, true); //return value
};
```